# How to Export only selected columns using columnToggler

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, xls, data-export

Here I am using dataExporter for my table in primeFaces, It is successfully exported in type="xls" but the problem is that in addition I am using columnToggler for selection of columns and i want to target only those columns for export in xls file, those are checked/selected in columnToggler like:
[image]

here is code of my dataExporter which targeted my table (id = "tbl").

```
    <h:commandLink>
  <img src="Resources/images/excel.png"/>
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="dailyPoolReport_#{userAuthorization.user.loginName}" pageOnly="false" postProcessor="#{customizedDocumentsView.postProcessXLS}"/>
   </h:commandLink>
```

And here is my table code with columnToggler:

```
 <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="car" value="#{dailyTrackingBean.trackReportData}" rowIndexVar="row" style="font-size:12px; margin-bottom:0;"
                                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                                 rowKey="#{car.vehicle.regNo}"
                                                 paginator="true" rows="50" rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,500,1000,5000">


<f:facet name="header" >
 <h:outputText value="Vehicle Tracking Summary Report" style="font-size: 14px"/>

   <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns" style="float:right;height: 22px;font-size: 11px" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
<p:columnToggler datasource="tbl" trigger="toggler" >

  </p:columnToggler>

 </f:facet>
```

Is there is any possible solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do that you can use something similar to this:
http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3341

So you can have a list of boolean that represents the toogles for the attibute "visible" and can use the same for "exportable"

Ex:

```
<f:facet name="header">
   List of Cars
   <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns"  style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
   <p:columnToggler datasource="cars" trigger="toggler">
     <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{dtBasicView.onToggle}" />
   </p:columnToggler>
</f:facet>



 <p:column headerText="Id" visible="#{dtBasicView.list[0]}" exportable="#{dtBasicView.list[0]}">
                   <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
 </p:column>
```

Another plus - If you use the above also evading:

* The problem (columntoggler and pagination)

* The problem (columntoggler and globalfilter)

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: This worked for me. Hopever since I am using dynamically generated columns (ie <p:columns/>) I need to use the "update" attribute in my <p:ajax/> tag or else the visible and exportable attributes will not show up on the jsf page.