# How to exclude hidden columns (hidden by using p:columnToggler ) from Exported file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable, export

**Remark:** I tried  https://www.primefaces.org/stateful-column-toggler/ but it's not working.
I am using p:columnToggler to hide column of p:dataTable it's working fine,but when i am using Export as .pdf/.csv/.xls the hidden columns are also coming into Exported file.
**Requirements:**I want excludethose hiddden columns in Exported file.
i am using columnToggler like:`<p:columnToggler datasource="cars" trigger="toggler" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Export only selected columns using columnToggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115782/how-to-export-only-selected-columns-using-columntoggler)

Comment: I followed the same way what is mentioned on https://www.primefaces.org/stateful-column-toggler/ but it's only hiding the column from dataTable but in export, i am getting all column, in short, this solution is not working

Comment: Finally, I solved it.I followed  primefaces.org/stateful-column-toggler  but instead of setting visible="" i used exportable=""     
<p:column headerText="Id" exportable="#{dtBasicView.list[0]}">
<h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
</p:column>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post an answer, so after a long time, I am posting it may this help someone.
I followed primefaces.org/stateful-column-toggler but instead of setting visible="" I used exportable=""

```
<p:column headerText="Id" exportable="#{dtBasicView.list[0]}"> <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /> </p:column>
```